# weather-indicator: networking error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden?

Tags: 12.10, indicator, weather

Here're the `~/.cache/indicator-weather.log`:

```
[Fetcher] 2012-11-24 11:45:52,619 - DEBUG - Indicator: getWeather for location 'Hanoi, Ha Nội, Vietnam'
[Fetcher] 2012-11-24 11:45:52,620 - DEBUG - Indicator: getWeather: updating weather report
[Fetcher] 2012-11-24 11:45:52,620 - DEBUG - Location: default weather source 'Google' chosen for 'Hanoi'
[Fetcher] 2012-11-24 11:45:53,019 - ERROR - Indicator: networking error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
[Fetcher] 2012-11-24 11:45:53,020 - DEBUG - Indicator: updateWeather: waiting for 'Cacher' thread to terminate
[Fetcher] 2012-11-24 11:45:53,020 - ERROR - Indicator: updateWeather: could not get weather, leaving cached data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[Fetcher] 2012-11-24 11:45:52,620 - DEBUG - Location: default weather source 'Google' chosen for 'Hanoi'
[Fetcher] 2012-11-24 11:45:53,019 - ERROR - Indicator: networking error: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

It looks like there is some problems when connecting to Google Data Source. Switching to Yahoo! and it's working fine:

[image]